# Librarian Chef and Local Chef Server

Tags: chef-infra, librarian

We are trying to use Librarian Chef with a local corporate chef server. This Chef Server Requires Authentication and is running version 12. When attempting to use Librarian Chef with this Server, It appears that it will not authenticate. I get a response with the html content of the login page. I was hoping to find a way to get this to work.

I have used berks (using berks install --path /some/path) in the past to manage a cookbook packages but it appears the newer versions do not support creating a global dependency management and only work on individual cookbook dependencies.

**** Note the librarian and librarian-chef repos appear to be abandonded
https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian-chef
https://github.com/applicationsonline/librarian
These should be avoided.

After some more research it appears the command for berks gives me the same effect as the command noted above in the newer versions

berks vendor ./some/path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Librarian has been abandoned for many years. It is not recommended in any way. Use Berkshelf or Policyfiles if you want a supported UX, or maybe Batali if you want something off the beaten path (just don't expect to get much help if you go that route). Berks works fine for global dependency management, in fact that's the cornerstone of the environment cookbook pattern.

Comment: If you don’t put a `metadata` line in your berksfile, it won’t look for a metadata.rb file.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding librarian, I was not aware that it was abandoned. As far as using Berks, I have been trying to figure out how to use it outside the scope, within a cookbook. Every command I have tried looks for a metadata.rb file. In earlier versions of the product, all I would need is a berksfile and a berksfile.config file and I could package my cookbooks and dependancies. I have not found a way to do this with the newer versions. Edit****. Based on coderanger's comment, this is the acceptable answer. Thanks ******